# Generating a comprehensive callgraph using GCC & Egypt

Tags: linux, gcc, static-libraries, call-graph

I am trying to generate a comprehensive callgraph (complete with low level calls to Linux, runtime, the lot).

I have statically compiled my source files with "-fdump-rtl-expand" and created RTL files, which I passed to a PERL script called Egypt (which I believe is Graphviz/Dot) and generated a PDF file of the callgraph. This works perfectly, no problems at all.

Except, there are calls being made into some libraries that are getting shown as built-in. I was looking to see if there is a way for the callgraph not to be printed as  and instead the real calls made into the libraries ?

Please let me know if the question is unclear.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWoAC.jpg

Basically, I am trying to avoid the callgraph from generating < built-in >

Is there a way to do that ?

-------- CODE ---------

```
#include <cilk/cilk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long int t0, t5;
unsigned int NOSPAWN_THRESHOLD = 32;

int fib_nospawn(int n)
{
  if (n < 2) 
    return n;
  else 
    {
      int x = fib_nospawn(n-1);
      int y = fib_nospawn(n-2);
      return x + y;
    }
}

// spawning fibonacci function
int fib(long int n)
{
  long int x, y;
  if (n < 2) 
    return n;
  else if (n <= NOSPAWN_THRESHOLD)
    {
      x = fib_nospawn(n-1);
      y = fib_nospawn(n-2);
      return x + y;
    }
  else 
    {
      x = cilk_spawn fib(n-1);
      y = cilk_spawn fib(n-2);
      cilk_sync;
      return x + y;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int n;
  long int result;
  long int exec_time;

  n = atoi(argv[1]);
  NOSPAWN_THRESHOLD = atoi(argv[2]);
  result = fib(n);

  printf("%ld\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled the Cilk Library from source.

Comment: Can you post some sample code that produces `<built-in>`.  The code I tried didn't produce any `built-in` in the `rtl` or `dotty` output from `egypt`. Also, are you looking to just remove the `<built-in>` node, or it and its child nodes.  And I assume the `egypt -omit` option didn't meet your requirements. Also, what version of gcc and what other command line options are you using.  The rtl file I got out of gcc 4.1.2 didn't include the parameter descriptions.

Comment: Thanks... Added code as EDIT to question

Comment: You might do better basing it on a dump later in the compilation process? Expand produces a lot of cruft that gets culled out later. If you want to see all functions you'll need to disable inlining though.

Comment: @ams: Thanks for your comment. I understand that the "-dumpspecs" option in GCC prints all the builtin specs. How can I route this into the RTL files ? Do you follow a better method ?

Comment: I added "--include-external" to egypt but this still seems produce the "built-in" specs - http://i.imgur.com/GWPJO.jpg?1

Comment: `-dumpspecs` is not related to the RTL debugging dumps. If you want to see what dumps are available, try `-fdump-rtl-all`. You might also find `-fdump-tree-all` and `-fdump-ipa-all` educational. In fact, `-fdump-ipa-cgraph` might be just what you need, although it won't take later optimizations (that might add or remove function calls) into account.

Comment: @ams Thank you for your reply. Can you pipe the *.cgraph file to a pictorial representing tool ? I passed it through egypt and then dot seems to reject it.

Answer (score 4):

I might have found the **partial solution** to the problem:

You need to pass the following option to egypt

```
--include-external
```

This produced a slightly more comprehensive callgraph, although there still is the " visible

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj18x.jpg

Can anyone suggest if I get more depth in the callgraph ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GCC VCG Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/gcc-vcg-plugin/): A gcc plugin, which can be loaded when debugging gcc, to show internal structures graphically.

`gcc -fplugin=/path/to/vcg_plugin.so -fplugin-arg-vcg_plugin-cgraph foo.c`

Call-graph is place to store data needed
for inter-procedural optimization. All datastructures
are divided into three components:
`local_info` that is produced while analyzing
the function, `global_info` that is result
of global walking of the call-graph on the end
of compilation and `rtl_info` used by RTL
back-end to propagate data from already compiled
functions to their callers.