# File/symbol dependency graph visualisation for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, dependencies, visualization, dependency-management

I am well aware of Doxygen's ability to visualise the function call graph and file-level include dependency graph. I'm interested in a tool to give a visual overview of a whole project's file-level dependencies in a single graph. The nodes of the graph would be modules/objects, e.g. Foo.cpp/hpp files would considered a single entity and be a single node "Foo". Doxygen's include dependency graph only shows the include chain of a single file, as far as I'm aware.

It would seem the two ways to do this would be:

1. Symbol dependencies of the object files - so this tool would take the compiled object files as input.
2. Include dependencies, but each node is the combined source and header file, rather than just the headers. This tool would take the source files as input, and relies on A.cpp having a corresponding A.hpp in a findable location. This method would result in some extra dependency edges for non-symbol dependencies, as well as unnecessary include dependencies.

Is there such a tool that does this, preferably free?

Comment: There may be useful information in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184219/generating-a-comprehensive-callgraph-using-gcc-egypt

Comment: The diagrams in the question there all have functions for nodes instead of files - I'm after files as nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [CppDepend](https://www.cppdepend.com), it takes as input the source code and gives you the possibility to have advanced dependency graphs using our code query language to filter what you want to be in the graph.

Comment: Thanks, I tried CppDepend on Linux, but it seemed a bit half-baked with an unintuitive interface and too many UI exceptions and crashes for me to consider using.